# Laravel vapor migrate from local to vapor

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I am trying to migrate my local Laravel app to Laravel serverless Vapor,
I installed, Vapor Core and CLI in my project root,

Below is a snippet of composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0.2",
    "diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.6",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
    "laravel/vapor-cli": "^1.59",
    "laravel/vapor-core": "^2.32",
    "laravel/vapor-ui": "^1.7",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.12",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^10.0"
```

now I moved to my project directory in the terminal, and when I tried to login with Vapor, it showed `command not found`

```bash
me@MyPC:~/oicluster6$ vapor login
vapor: command not found
me@MyPC:~/oicluster6$
```

What could be a possible issue with vapor installation or login?

Comment: Have you installed it globally? Did you tried this, ./vendor/bin/vapor